# How to override distutils commands by cmdclass in a cfg file?

Tags: setuptools, setup.py, distutils, python-packaging

I am migrating the configurations from `setup.py` to `setup.cfg` but I have a problem with `cmdclass` keyword. I looked into setuptools docs and it seems like this keyword is not documented or supported. So I tried `options.entry_points` instead. But I keep getting invalid command error.

Here is what I have:

`setup.cfg`

```
[options.entry_points]
console_scripts =
    install = CustomInstall:run
```

and

`setup.py`

```
from setuptools.command.install import install
from setuptools import setup

class CustomInstall(install):
    def run(self):
        print('overriden install command')

setup()
```

The result was just a normal install command. However, I would like to replicate the behaviour that I get when I run:

```
# setup.py
from setuptools.command.install import install
from setuptools import setup

class CustomInstall(install):
    def run(self):
        print('overriden install command')

setup(cmdclass= {"install": CustomInstall})
```

which gives an overriden install command.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe it's possible. Leave it in the `setup.py`.

Answer (score 2):

It is not supported.

See [this PR](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/pull/1828) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The `cmdclass` keyword in `setup.cfg` has been [fixed in v54](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/main/CHANGES.rst#v5400). It is still not documented though.

Now you can do:

**`setup.cfg` (only part)**

```cfg
[options]
cmdclass =
    install = build.MyInstall
```

**`build.py`**

```python
from setuptools.command.install import install

class MyInstall(install):

    def run(self):
        print("Custom install start")
        super().run()
        print("Custom install done")
```

Both files are located in the root of project.

When you run `python setup.py install`, the custom install script gets triggered. This setup is equivalent to the `setup(cmdclass=...)` you used.

Answer (score 0):

What `[options.entry_points]` and `console_scripts` does is create shell commands which run specific functions in your code base. These commands will work once your package has been installed in an environment.

So in your example, a new shell command `install` would be created, and it would run the `run()` function from a package called `CustomInstall`.

Based on looking at source code, I would *guess* the correct syntax is instead:

```py
[global]
commands =
  install = mypackage.CustomInstall
```

but I haven't been able to make it work either yet.